# How to create directory dynamically?

Tags: php

I have the code below but I want to write the file under a dynamically created folder from date. So it should look like this date/filename.txt

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
        $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
        $filename = date('YmdHis').".txt";
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
        }
        $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
       die('no post data to process');
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mkdir function to create directory:

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
        $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
        mkdir(date('YmdHis'));
        $filename = date('YmdHis')."/filename.txt";
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
        }
        $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
       die('no post data to process');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Mate ok but i don't wanna change my filename i only want to add directory from date. So output should look like this date/date.txt .

Comment: date('YmdHis')."/" . date('YmdHis') . ".txt"; like this?

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSS=))) Thanks a lot. I don't know how to use "/" double quotes etc. so i get syntax errors but you fixed it=)) Greatt

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
 if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
   mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
 }
```

Comment: thanks should i replace this "path/to/directory" with "date('Ymd')" this?

Comment: depend in which diretory you store the subdir date(Ymd)

Comment: i want it to be like this 20160107/20160107.txt